# TL431 - negative and positive references point

Tags: diodes, voltage-regulator, voltage-reference

I am a musician who likes to play around with electronics.

For some synthesizer circuits I am working on I need to create two references points using the TL431 - one for negative 2.5V and the other for positive 10V. I have a power supply of +-12V dc.

After looking around the web I came with these two circuits:

[image]

I checked both with DMM and both gave me the voltage references I needed.

There are two things I would like to ask in both circuits:

1. Should I add a resistor before the references points in order to limit the current? In the top circuit from the anode lug and in the bottom one from the cathode lug . If so what should its value be?
   Can I use those references points at other points in the circuit without resistor?
2. I placed a 1.5k resistor from the power rails to the TL431 (in the top circuit from the -12V rail to the anode and in the bottom circuit from the +12V rail to the cathode) but I'm not sure why other then it was recommended to me earlier. I guess different values will limit the current that goes to and out from the TL431, but how do you know what value to choose?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Can I use those references points at other points in the circuit
> without resistor?*

You can but, if whatever is receiving the reference voltage can cause it to short out then you need to ensure that the 1.5 kΩ resistor in each circuit is adequately power-rated.

> *but how do you know what value to choose?*

You choose a value that prevents excessive current flow into the TL431 when there is zero load current at the output. So, in your upper picture (the -2.5 volt reference), the TL431 will naturally be taking a current of: -

$$\dfrac{12 \text{ volts} - 2.5 \text{ volts}}{1500 \text{ }\Omega} = 6.333 \text{ mA}$$

And, given that the TL431 can sink up to 100 mA, 6.333 mA doesn't seem much of a problem. I guess for most optimum regulation 10 mA should be aimed for because most specifications in [the data sheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl431.pdf?ts=1607949893640&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) assume the TL431 takes 10 mA nominally.

You must also ensure that the current is greater than 1 mA or regulation will be poor.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  it is much clearer now to me